# Swap mouse move for touch control

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html5-canvas

I have this script for moving a character in a game in a html 5 canvas, it simply calls a function to move the character if the mouse is detected either side. How would I swap that for a touch gesture to be used on a mobile device?

```
document.onmousemove = function(e){  
    if (player.X + c.offsetLeft > e.pageX) {  
        player.moveLeft();  
    } else if (player.X + c.offsetLeft < e.pageX) {  
        player.moveRight();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend swapping it out.  Instead just add handlers for touch events and translate the events into something your `onmousemove` handler can understand.

So for instance, add an `ontouchmove` handler that translates the event's `screenX` and `screenY` to `pageX` and `pageY` and then calls your existing `onmousemove` handler.  That would be for [handling events from iOS devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) running mobile Safari.  You'll probably have to add some additional translations to handle other devices/browsers as well.

Comment: cheers, sort of worked, got it to move a little but then stopped. need to figure out how to loop movement until touchend.

Comment: A flag and a `setTimeout` loop would probably work.  Something like `function movementLoop() { document.onmousemove(touchPoint); if(flag) setTimeout(movementLoop, 100); }`

Comment: something like this http://ross.posterous.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript/